# Why do Python's empty classes and functions work as arbitrary data containers, but not other objects?

Tags: python

I've seen two different Python objects used to group arbitrary data together: empty classes and functions.

```
def struct():
    pass

record = struct
record.number = 3
record.name = "Zoe"


class Struct:
    pass

record = Struct()
record.number = 3
record.name = "Zoe"
```

Even if the class isn't empty, it seems to work so long as it's defined at runtime.

But when I got cocky and tried to do this with built-in functions or classes, it didn't work.

```
record = set()
record.number = 3
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'number'

record = pow
pow.number = 3
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'number'
```

Is there a fundamental difference between built-in and "custom" classes and functions that accounts for this behavior?

Comment: There's a bug in your first example: it should be `record = struct` withouth the `()`, otherwise `record` will be `None` and the next line will throw an exception. Also, it should be noted that using functions only works because a user-defined function is just another object in python, meaning you can assign arbitrary attributes. If the function is empty or not doesn't have anything to do with it either. But while you can probably use this for some funky meta-/dynamic-programming magic, I can't think of a reason why using a function as a storage container would be preferable over a class...

Comment: @l4mpi I think it's useful if you want to emulate closures that "write" to their enclosing scope in Python 2.x, before `nonlocal`. You use ad-hoc attributes of the local function object instead of local vars.

Comment: Oops, you're right about the first example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that both function objects and your Struct object have a `__dict__` attribute, but `set` instances and built-in functions do not:

```
>>> def struct():
...     pass
...
>>> record = struct
>>> record.number = 2
>>> struct.__dict__
{'number': 2}
>>> class Struct:
...     pass
...
>>> record = Struct()
>>> record.number = 3
>>> record.__dict__
{'number': 3}
>>> record=set()
>>> record.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> pow.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

In classes you can emulate the behavour using slots (although only on new-style classes):

```
>>> class StructWithSlots(object):
...     __slots__ = []
...
>>> record = StructWithSlots()
>>> record.number = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'StructWithSlots' object has no attribute 'number'
>>> record.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'StructWithSlots' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Answer (score 3):

Built-in types are written in C and cannot be modified like that. But after the [type/class unification](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/) introduced in py2.2 you can now inherit from a built-in types and override or add your own attributes to that subclass.

You can use the [forbiddenfood](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forbiddenfruit) package to add attributes to built-in types:

> This project aims to give you the way to find heaven in tests, but it
>   might lead you to **hell** if you use it on production code.

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse 
>>> def words_of_wisdom(self):
 ...     return self * "blah "
>>> curse(int, "words_of_wisdom", words_of_wisdom)
>>> assert (2).words_of_wisdom() == "blah blah "
```

And of course if you're cocky enough then you can create your own types in C and add such features to it.

Comment: Certainly one can create a type in C which can be used like that?

Comment: @delnan E.g. the `object` type. It might be interesting to dive into the Python source which one is the special case - allowing expando objects or preventing them.

Comment: @delnan But I wouldn't call it a built-in type then because you're writing your own type in C(it's not from standard library). The question is about built-in and custom classes.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question in any useful fashion - there's a higher-level answer than talking about the C code (which is only appropriate for CPython anyway): objects you can set arbitrary attributes on define `__dict__`, ones you cannot, don't.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Substitute "Python core developers" for "one". In other words, the builtin types don't reject additional attributes because they are written in C, they could be written in C and accept additional attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Some built-ins can be more restrictive.  Also, classes implemented with slots won't accept arbitrary attributes either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some simular protection in your own class, you can use the `__setattr__()` method.

```
class TestClass(object):
    # Accept the attributes in this list
    __valid_attributes = ["myattr1", "myattr2"]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not name in TestClass.__valid_attributes:
            raise AttributeError(
                "{0} has no attribute '{1}'".format(self.__class__.__name__, name))
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
t = TestClass()
t.noattr = "test" # AttributeError: TestClass has no attribute 'noattr'
```

But "valid attributes" can still be set:

```
t = TestClass()
t.myattr1 = "test"
print(t.myattr1) # test
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've just reinvented the [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) wheel.